# How to avoid big blinking cursor in the beginning and end of HTML table?

Tags: google-chrome, html, css, html5, html-files

I have observed that when viewing HTML tables in Google Chrome, when we click in the beginning or end of the table (left-most or right-most), a big blinking cursor is shown next to it.  How to avoid that?  I have written a sample piece of HTML code that simulates this issue:

```
<html>
<head><title>test cursor</title></head>
<body>
<table>
        <tr><td>col1</td><td>col2</td></tr>
        <tr><td>col1</td><td>col2</td></tr>
        <tr><td>col1</td><td>col2</td></tr>
        <tr><td>col1</td><td>col2</td></tr>
        <tr><td>col1</td><td>col2</td></tr>
        <tr><td>col1</td><td>col2</td></tr>
        <tr><td>col1</td><td>col2</td></tr>
        <tr><td>col1</td><td>col2</td></tr>
        <tr><td>col1</td><td>col2</td></tr>
        <tr><td>col1</td><td>col2</td></tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

The big line on the right side is actually the blinking cursor. I am using Chrome browser version 87.0.4280.88 (Official Build) (64-bit).

How to avoid this big blinking cursor?  Thanks!

Comment: Can you add a screenshot showing the issue? Use the [edit] button.

Comment: I made a simple html file using that exact code and did not get the same result (firefox and edge chromium). How are you viewing the table, just by opening an html file or are you deploying on a server?

Comment: That's true, issue is not in Firefox and Edge, but in Chrome browser.

Comment: Doesn't happen in Chrome. Possibly this is done by some installed extension.

Comment: I have tried disabling all extensions in Chrome, and then checked, no good, I still see this big cursor.

Comment: the OP text could mislead the readers. The cursor is not linked to HTML tables especially, it appears anywhere, text, images, tables, titles...

Answer (score 4):

Solved: I found the issue. It has to do with the Accessibility features of Chrome. I tried this:

Settings->Accessibility->Navigate pages with a text cursor

It was enabled, and I disabled it and the issue got fixed.